# Assigning a Unique reference and reference it to another collection

Tags: xslt

I am new to xml and am trying to add in a link between two collections by inserting a Position() number which I have added into the StyleCollection.  I now need to insert this as a StyleLink into the PackingLineCollection where the StyleNumber is equal to the StyleNumber in the StyleCollection. Can anybody point me in the right direction?
Here is the Input:

```
      <Order>
    <UniqueReferenceNumber>Order1234</UniqueReferenceNumber>
     <StyleCollection>
        <Style>
          <StyleNumber>1234</StyleNumber>
          <StyleType>
            <Code>abc</Code>
          </StyleType>
         <LocationNumber></LocationNumber>
        </Style>

        <Style>
          <StyleNumber>567</StyleNumber>
          <StyleType>
            <Code>xyz</Code>
          </StyleType>
         <LocationNumber></LocationNumber>
        </Style>
      </StyleCollection>
    <SubOrderCollection>
       <SubOrder>
          <UniqueReferenceNumber>SubOrder1</UniqueReferenceNumber>
            <PackingLineCollection>
                <PackingLine>
                <StyleNumber>1234</StyleNumber>
               </PackingLine>
        </PackingLineCollection>
        </SubOrder>
      <SubOrder>
          <UniqueReferenceNumber>SubOrder2</UniqueReferenceNumber>
            <PackingLineCollection>
                <PackingLine>
                <StyleNumber>xyz</StyleNumber>
              </PackingLine>
          </PackingLineCollection>
        </SubOrder>
    </SubOrderCollection>
  </Order>
```

Here is the xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" mlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match ="/">
<Order>
    <Reference>
      <xsl:value-of select="Order/UniqueReferenceNumber"/>
    </Reference>

      <StyleCollection>
        <xsl:for-each select="Order/StyleCollection/Style">
          <Style>
            <StyleNumber>
              <xsl:value-of select="StyleNumber"/>
            </StyleNumber>
          <LocationNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()"/> 
        </LocationNumber>                
            <StyleType>
              <Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="StyleType/Code"/>
              </Code>
            </StyleType>
          </Style>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </StyleCollection>

    <SubOrderCollection>
      <xsl:for-each select="Order/SubOrderCollection/SubOrder">
        <SubOrder>
          <Reference><xsl:value-of select="UniqueReferenceNumber"/> 
          </Reference>
          <PackingLineCollection>
            <xsl:for-each select="PackingLineCollection/PackingLine">
              <PackingLine>
                <StyleNumber>
                  <xsl:value-of select="StyleNumber" />
                </StyleNumber>
                <StyleLink><xsl:value-of 
Select="Order/StyleCollection/Style/LocationNumber"/></StyleLink>
               </PackingLine>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </PackingLineCollection>
        </SubOrder>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </SubOrderCollection>
  </Order>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are populating `<LocationNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></LocationNumber>`, for which other element do you also want that number? Or are you talking about the `StyleNumber` element? And how do you relate a `Style` and a `SubOrder`, simply by the same position in `StyleCollection` and `SubOrderCollection`?

Comment: Hi Martin.  The LocationNumber needs to be inserted into the StyleLink where the StyleNumber in the SubOrder is equal to that of the StyleNumber in the StyleCollection. So, where Order/StyleCollection/Style/StyleNumber = Order/SubOrderCollection/SubOrder/PackingLineCollection/PackingLine/StyleNumber then the Order/StyleCollection/Style/LocationNumber (that is generated in the xslt) must inserted into Order/SubOrderCollection/SubOrder/PackingLineCollection/PackingLine/StyleLink this is essentially creating a numeric key value for each Style number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented it using a key and `xsl:number` as follows (in XSLT 3 but the key and xsl:number should work in XSLT 1 or 2 as well, you would need to replace the used `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` with the identity transformation template):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="style-ref" match="StyleCollection/Style" use="StyleNumber"/>

  <xsl:template match="Style/LocationNumber">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:number from="StyleCollection" level="any"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PackingLine/StyleNumber">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('style-ref', .)" mode="count"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Style" mode="count">
      <StyleLink>
          <xsl:number level="any" from="StyleCollection"/>
      </StyleLink>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQt/1 however does not find a matching `Style` for the second `PackingLine/StyleNumber`, not sure whether your example data is meant to have no reference there or whether I misunderstood your requirements.

XSLT 1 is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="style-ref" match="StyleCollection/Style" use="StyleNumber"/>

  <xsl:template match="Style/LocationNumber">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:number from="StyleCollection" level="any"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PackingLine/StyleNumber">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('style-ref', .)" mode="count"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Style" mode="count">
      <StyleLink>
          <xsl:number level="any" from="StyleCollection"/>
      </StyleLink>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQt/2

Comment: Thank you for this. You were correct I had made a mistake in my example. I have tested using XSLT 1 and it does exactly what I need.